# save selected items global

Tags: javascript, html, select

I have an general question. My plan is, to make a form, where the user choose something of a select box, which influence another select box.

An example would be, that i have many restaurants. So first the user can choose: italian, spain, greek, american. It´s the style of the restaurant. And then on the next select box he can choose all italian Restaurants (or whatever he choosed first).

I already did an Ionic application. There it is very easy. I use a provider, save the variables and use in front of each restaurant *ngIf.

But how would be the solution on a normal website? Especially, if i wanna save the choose of the user and show him the restaurant on the next page?

hope someone has an idea.

Comment: If you want to persist a state across different pages (e.g. user choice on the type of cuisine in your case), you will have to store it in session storage, local storage, or cookies.

Comment: hm, i don´t really have an idea of this. but i will read some tutorials next days. thx